# Converting a Google-esque Search Query to search a Mongo database via Node.js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to be able to translate a search string in "Google-eqsue" format into something that can be used to search a Mongo database (I assume that RegEx is a good idea here, but am open to other ideas). What I mean by Google-esque queries:

```
"Search for" +this -"but not this"
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a Javascript algorithm that will take the Google-esque query and return something that will allow me to perform a single, fast query on the text of documents in a MongoDB. The reason I assumed that it would be best to translate this into a RegExp is that Regular Expressions fit these goals (edited).

Comment: Your reasons are wrong. Regex can (and do) differ quite a lot between languages.

Comment: Sigh. Fair enough. Let's confine the reasoning to Mongo + Node.js, then.

Comment: And, there are cross-platform languages that you could use to get the same portability. If I were you, I'd create the wheel you wish to use.

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully better illustrate the problem, then. I would like to execute a single query upon a Mongo database; my assumption was that RegExp was the best approach.

Comment: I don't know anything about Mongo, but usually using a single regex to search for such multiple match conditions (would look like `^(?=.*Search for this)(?=.*this)(?!.*but not this)`) isn't very efficient (on large strings).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try mongo's new [text search](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40513621310/mongodb-text-search-experimental-feature-in-mongodb) feature?

From the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/)

> With phrases (i.e. terms enclosed in escaped quotes), the search performs an AND with any other terms in the search string; e.g. search for "\"twinkle twinkle\" little star" searches for "twinkle twinkle" and ("little" or "star").

and

> Search for documents that contain the words bake or coffee, but not cake:

```
db.collection.runCommand( "text", { search: "bake coffee -cake" } )
```

> Use the - as a prefix to terms to specify negation in the search string. The query returns documents that contain the either bake or coffee, but not cake, all case-insensitive, in the content field.

Comment: Oh man, that's exactly what I want! Amazing that it has just been anounced in the last week or so. Unfortunately... I'm stuck with MongoDB 2.0.2 on my production servers, so it's not an option :(